# ui-router: Routes that have same URLs but different states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm running into an issue where two different states but have the same URL. It seems like ui-router doesn't know which one to navigate to.

Basically, I defined 2 states:

- Name: `app.page`, url: `/:pageID`
- Name: `app.contact`, url: `/contact`

When I call `$state.go('app.contact')`, it loads the `app.page` state instead.

What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: How are those the same url?

Comment: @Noppey what if I create a page with id = `contact`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uh oh, I found the answer, just change the state definition order, bring `app.contact` state definition before `app.page` state definition code.

(For those who have the same problem)